# What exactly does the 's' parameter search for in WP queries?

Tags: wp-query

I have a simple question, but can't find the answer anywhere. What exactly does the 's' parameter search when used in a query? Ex:

`$args = array(
    's' => $keyword
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);`

Does it just search post content, or does it also look at title, tags, etc?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify. The question is what post fields are being searched, not what data is being returned.

Comment: The default fields being searched are post content and post title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As usual it's most reliable to dump the resulting SQL query and see:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%keyword%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%keyword%')))
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

The only two things native search is considering are title and content.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! I didn't realize that you could dump the query itself but I'll check that out

Comment: `$wpdb->last_query` :)